# Am I able to ask specific users a question?

Tags: discussion, support

If I've read answers from a specific handler and think they seem super knowledgeable in a subject I'm curious about am I then able to PM or ask that specific user a question? Or is this discouraged? Or is there no way to do this?  I looked in the "how to ask a question" tips n didn't see....Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy for you to ping me any time you like to get a second opinion or an answer, if I'm able to. That community is important. That we feel connected.   Also, if you want to provide an answer and want some feedback, I'm happy to help with that also. Please feel free to do the same with mine. :)

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thanks! I will do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All new questions are published for all to see, there is no way to bring a specific question to the attention of a specific user.  Using the correct tags will increase the likelihood that users who specialize in specific areas will see the question.

Keep in mind, everyone here is a volunteer. No one is obligated to answer any question.

If someone is active in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) you can get their attention by preceeding their name with '@' for me it would be @JamesJenkins when you start typing @jam... you should get an auto complete option.  If the auto complete does not show, the user will not be notified, as they don't have enough activity in the space to complete the call.

If you have [sufficient rep](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can add comments below an existing post and include a link to a new question. This is sometimes used (*in moderation*) for closely related Q&A.